# Unable to ping or access internet

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, internet, nat

I am setting up a private network. The server is Windows 2008 R2 with DNS installed and has a fixed external IP address. ipconfig outputs the following:

PPP adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.16.7

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.16.2

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5c6a:b01f:2d23:92f8%11

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : FIXED IP ADDRESS

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : FIXED IP ADDRESS

Other machines on the network aquire IP address like 192.168.16.15. However, none of these machines can ping any public sever (e.g., www.yahoo.com) or has the internet connection.

Another note: All these machines can browse to a website until I installed Visual Studio 2008 and TFS Team Explorer on the server.

In response to Boden's question, here are outputs from various commands executed on a client machine:

ping www.yahoo.com:

Pinging www-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com [209.191.93.52] with 32 bytes of data: 
Request timed out. 
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

ipconfig:

```
 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection: 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : DomainName 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.16.13 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.16.2
```

nslookup www.yahoo.com:

```
Server: UnKnown 
Address: 192.168.16.2 

Non-authoritative answer: 
Name: www-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com 
Address: 209.191.93.52 
Aliases:  www.yahoo.com
          www.wa1.b.yahoo.com
```

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: Does ping correctly resolve the name?  What does ipconfig report on the other machines (esp. default gateway)?

Comment: I modified the question to include more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing - but do you have routing enabled between local & public interface on the server? Probably during the VS installation it got disabled.

Comment: How do you check if the routing betwen the local and public interfaces is enabled? Thanks.

Comment: run "route print" in the command line and post the results here

Answer (score 0):

To start from the bottom. 
**1.** From the client. Can you ping the default gateway?
-I see it is your server. If you can't. Can you ping the pc from the server?
-I also see the nic doesn't have a default gateway. Have you tried setting the gateway to the LAN 2 for 192.168.16.2? Can you ping successfully now?
**2.** Can you ping it's DNS server? Ipconfig /all should tell you what it is.
**3.** Can you ping the external DNS server from the client. Should be able to see that from the DNS forwarders setup on your server.
-Can you ping the DNS server from the server?

Answer (score 0):

As nhek alluded to, try to enable TCP/IP forwarding on the server.
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q230082